# ¿Cómo de-seleccionar un item de un ComboBox al teclar esc dentro de un Grid?

Tags: vb.net, gridview

Que tal, tengo un Grid con dos columnas en una de ellas tengo una columna de tipo ComboBoxColumn, el combo lo lleno el evento Load del formulario, lo que quiero hacer es que cada vez que seleccione un item del combo y quiera des-seleccionarlo en cualquier momento lo pueda hacer cuando se teclea esc.

Comment: Se retiró la etiqueta visual-basic porque es ambigua y se ha sugerido su quemado. Véase https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1045/65

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución a la pregunta que realice, espero les sirva y si alguien contribuye a algo mejor lo pueden hacer.

Lo que hice fue en el evento de KeyPress del Grid detecte si la tecla pulsada era la tecla esc busco la celda activa seleccionada del Grid y pongo el value en cadena vacía.

```
Private Sub dgvHojas_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles dgvHojas.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(27) Then
        sender.CurrentCell.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```